# html to csv data parsing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I am converting html tables into CSV format using python.

Code :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import csv
import argparse

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Reads in an HTML and attempts to convert all tables into CSV files.')
parser.add_argument('--delimiter', '-d', action='store', default=',',help="Character with which to separate CSV columns")
parser.add_argument('--quotechar', '-q', action='store', default='"',help="Character within which to nest CSV text")
parser.add_argument('filename',nargs="?",help="HTML file from which to extract tables")
args = parser.parse_args()

if sys.stdin.isatty() and not args.filename:
  parser.print_help()
  sys.exit(-1)
elif not sys.stdin.isatty():
  args.filename = sys.stdin
else:
  args.filename = open(sys.argv[1],'r')

print "Opening file"
fin  = args.filename.read()

print "Parsing file"
soup = BeautifulSoup(fin,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

print "Preemptively removing unnecessary tags"
[s.extract() for s in soup('script')]

print "CSVing file"
tablecount = -1
for table in soup.findAll("table"):
  tablecount += 1
  print "Processing Table #%d" % (tablecount)
  with open(sys.argv[1]+str(tablecount)+'.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        fout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=args.delimiter, quotechar=args.quotechar, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
          cols = row.findAll(['td','th'])
          if cols:
            cols = [x.text for x in cols]
            fout.writerow(cols)
```

Here I dont want to provide the sys arguments explicitly, instead I want it to be hardcoded inside script with the file name.
present usage is - python html2csv.py test.html.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Error :

```
File "html2csv.py", line 17, in <module>
if sys.stdin.isatty() and not args.filename:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

Comment: you want to omit "test.html" in the script call, and it should take that filename as default?

Comment: Oh I didnot get you exactly where it should be ?

Comment: Sorry :) I was trying to ask what exactly you are trying to achieve. what shall be harcoded, only the filename test.html? And what operating system are you working on?

Comment: Operating system is windows
and yes I dont want to provide the file (test.html) explicitly when runnning python html2csv.py file as sys argument
instead it should be hard coded inside html2csv.py file

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the opened file object is wrote to the variable `args.filename`

I would try (quick and very dirty) to add just before

```
print "Opening file"
fin  = args.filename.read()
```

the line

```
args.filename = open('test.html', 'r')
```

It might be, that the parser complains that you don't pass a filename to the command, but probably not, just try :)

Comment: It still asks fot the test.html file as arguments :-(

Comment: hm... the `parser` is quite a complicated object I do not know well. Try removing the line with `parser.add_argument('filename'...` and maybe also the `else: args.filename = open(sys.argv[1],'r')`

Comment: how does it "ask" for the argument, btw, the error message could help to understand, too

Comment: Added the error it returns above in question.
Tried out  the steps you recommended.

Comment: oh, yes, of course! You removed the `add_argument('filename'`-line, so the `if` can't evaluate, I see. Just remove the whole `if`-block, not just the last else, also the five lines before. _now_ it should work^^

Comment: may be we missed the line "with open(sys.argv[1]+str(tablecount)+'.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:"

what can be the alternative for this?

Comment: It would be really great if you can edit & mark out the changes, may be i am missing something as it doesn't give me the appropriate result